# Ehcache being emptied

Tags: java, hibernate, ehcache

I'm using Hibernate 4.2 and Ehcache 2.4.3 in my webapp and I've found out that my caches are constantly being cleared every few seconds (even the ones marked as eternal). There is no place in my code where I clear all the caches. Why is this happening?

Here is my ehcache.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ehcache>
  <diskStore path="java.io.tmp"/>

  <defaultCache
    maxElementsInMemory="1000000"
    eternal="false"
    overflowToDisk="false"
    memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU"/>

  <cache name="[class A]"
    maxElementsInMemory="250000"
    eternal="false"
    overflowToDisk="false"
    memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU"/>

  <cache name="[class B]"
    maxElementsInMemory="10"
    eternal="true"
    overflowToDisk="false"/>  
</ehcache>
```

Here are my Tomcat's JAVA_OPTS:

```
-server -Xms32G -Xmx32G -XX:PermSize=512m -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=200 -XX:ParallelGCThreads=20 -XX:ConcGCThreads=5 -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=70 -XX:+DisableExplicitGC
```

Comment: Please add information as to how you use Ehcache in your app. Is it used as Hibernate 2LC? Or directly with Spring?

Comment: @LouisJacomet it is indeed used as the Hibernate 2nd level cache and we don't  have Spring. I suspected that it might be the garbage collector's fault, but I switched the GC to UseConcMarkSweepGC and the problem persists. Do you need anything else? I'd be happy to provide any info.

Comment: Can you please add hibernate configuration information? Depending on the the configuration, some cache clears can happen in order to maintain consistency.